# Setting root view controller in didReceiveLocalNotification: results in black window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know different versions of this question has been asked before but I'm really stuck here. I'm trying to get my app to push a new view from my app delegate when getting:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotif {
```

And I put the following code in there:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
nvcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
[nvcontrol.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.window.rootViewController = nvcontrol;
```

and from this, I get a black view (which `myViewController` should not have) with a black navigation bar.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your project contains a MyViewController.xib file?

Comment: No, I have a UIViewController in my storyboard with the custom class MyViewController

Comment: @philipM well there's your problem. Although if you have a storyboard, why not just set the initial view controller to whatever you want? There's an arrow you can drag around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As I've outlined above, you can use storyboard to set the initial view controller.

Note that if you have a view controller set up in storyboard and then you create a view controller in the application delegate, the view controller you created won't look like your one in storyboard. This is because you are making an instance of the CLASS, but the program has no way to associate this with your layout.

Comment: I don't want it as initial view controller :) But you helped me realize the problem with the storyboard so I made a xib and now it works with: initWithNibName. Thank you for the help!